# Can't find glibc source code during remote debugging arm with eclipse

Tags: linux, arm, remote-debugging, gdbserver

I updated my toolchain to gcc 8.3 from arm developer website gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz

I can build the program and run it on the target, it works fine. But when i try to remote debug over eclipse I get the following error:

```
0xb6fd6a40 in _dl_start_user () from /home/user/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3

Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0xb6fe62a2 in _dl_fini () at dl-fini.c:87
87  dl-fini.c: No such file or directory.
```

Where can I find the source files and where should they be placed?

I noticed that earlier arm toolchain has a separate sysroot package but 8.3 is missing it.

Comment: Pro tip: write the function name or filename with "github" suffixed in google search like [`"dl-fini.c" github`](https://www.google.com/search?q="dl-fini.c"+github) and you usually find it.

Comment: I am wondering why I am even trying to debug in the glibc code, it is not my intention at all. I never reach my main function. Either I have not installed the toolchain properly on my host maching or something is missing from my beaglebone black.

Answer (score 0):

The problem resides due to the GCC 8.3 package that was downloaded from https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads

There is obviously something wrong with the gdb binary as it doesn't work as intended, instead it was possible to solve this issue by downloading from linaros homepage: https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-7/arm-linux-gnueabihf/